# Value from Dockerfile searchable in Sources tab - how to secure environment variables?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I've got a React web app where I read environment variables in from a `Dockerfile` that's deployed to Digital Ocean's App platform. If I search for the value's key, I can see the value out in all its glory. Did I do something wrong when I added the key?

Here's the key specified in Dockerfile:

```
ARG REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_live_51I...wzs
```

And here's the value after searching in the Sources tab in Chrome:

```
, E = n(309)
, G = Object(j.a)("pk_live_51I...wzs}")
```

How do I prevent this value from being accessible to the web?

Answer (score 0):

The Publishable API key is designed to be used client-side such as in a browser or a mobile app. This means they can be seen by anyone and this is not an issue with your code they were just designed this way and it is safe. The one you want to keep secret is the Secret API key (sk_live_123) instead!

Stripe has more details about this here: https://stripe.com/docs/keys